# Как с помощью JQuery выбрать часть контента?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я хочу выбрать содержимое ячейки таблицы, в ней записан текст и вставлена ссылка.
Мне нужно получить только текст. Не знаю, как правильно записать, что мне нужен 1 элемент из этой ячейки.

```
var text = $("#courses tr:eq(2) td:eq(1) ").html(); //  получаю текст и ссылку
```

Comment: приведите пример содержимого ячейки

Comment: можете попробовать использовать `.text()` метод

Comment: @Sergiks Содержимое ячейки:

Разработка веб - приложений (<a class="doc" href="#">ссылка</a>)

Comment: и какой результат вы рассчитываете получить в итоге?

Comment: Сейчас я получаю такой: Разработка веб - приложений (<a class="doc" href="#">ссылка</a>)

Хочу получить вот так: Разработка веб - приложений

Скобки в условии я уберу.

Comment: можно ли полагаться на скобки? Брать вместо `.html()` – `.text()` (это уберёт теги) и убрать скобки с содержимым.

Comment: @Sergics, теперь я получаю такой результат: Разработка веб - приложений (ссылка). Теперь бы обрезать то, что идёт до скобки и результат будет готов. Как это реализовать ?

Comment: Всё, я сделал. Полученный резалт через метод Split() по скобке сделал.

Comment: Напишите код ответом на свой вопрос – может быть, пригодится другим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, есть следующий html

```
<div class="some">
  Разработка веб - приложений (<a class="doc" href="#">ссылка</a>)
</div>
```

В памяти он представлен в виде дерева

```
DIV
   #text
   A
     #text
   #text
```

Если надо получить первый #text, то пишем

```
var div = $(".some")[0]; // jquery: найти class="some" и вернуть тег.  
var txt = div.childNodes[0].nodeValue
            .trim()  // убрать начальные и конечные пробелы
            .slice(0, -1);  // уменьшить длину строки на 1
```

Результат в txt

```
"Разработка веб - приложений "
```

Answer (score 1):

Реализовал для себя подобным образом:

```
var text = $("#courses tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)").text();
var text2 = text.split('(')[0];
```

Comment: вместо `split('(')[0]` можно `slice(0, -1)` -- посмотрите мой ответ